# How to create a validation rule so that only two users A and B can change values

Tags: formula, formula-field

I need to create a validation rule on two picklist fields n same custom objects so that only two users A and B with same profile can change values on that field,rest other users cannot change values.

Kindly help!!

Answer (score 1):

$User.Name or $Profile.Name should do the trick

Comment: Can you provide me the exact syntax.If I have two fields named Owner Proposal and Owner Close and only two users Alen and Jade can change the values of the lookup fields.Please help!!

Comment: AND 
( 
ISCHANGED(X), 

$Profile.Name <> "X", 
$User.Name <> "X", 
$User.Name <> "X", 
$User.Id <> "X" 
)

replace X's with the values you need

Comment: I am using the syntax AND ( ISCHANGED( Owner_Proposal__c ), $User.Username ='alen@abc.com'<> "Owner_Proposal__c ", $User.Username='jade@abc.com' <> "Owner_Proposal__c " ) but I am getting the syntax error further I would like to inform you that owner proposal is a look up field.

Comment: AND ( ISCHANGED( Owner_Proposal__c ), $User.Username <>'alen@abc.com', $User.Username<>'jade@abc.com')

try that